# to develop facebook app with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

Which is the best way for to develop a facebook app (Fan page) with Ruby on Rails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "best way". I use Koala and the FB JS API.

Comment: Thanks. This is just the information I was looking for!